# I'm having trouble with inputenc package clashing

Tags: packages, input-encodings

I get a "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc." in a line which is a blank line right after \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}.

```
\documentclass{RITA}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{[}
\renewcommand\citeright{]}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You called `inputenc` twice. Perhaps class `RITA` called it too.  Call it only one time, for example `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` ...

Comment: The option of inputenc should match the encoding of your tex file. Else, the package is pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

Your preamble has two consecutive `\usepackage{inputenc}` statements, but they are  loaded with mutually exclusive and incompatible options. (Just in case it isn't clear: A file can have only one input encoding at a time.) After `inputenc` has been loaded with the option `latin1`, it makes no sense to load the package again with the option `utf8` -- or vice versa. One would certainly never load the package with *both* options, right?

You need to decide which option is correct for *your* input file: Maybe it's `latin1`, maybe it's `utf8`, and maybe it's something else altogether. Only you can tell.

Comment: Also, it should be mentioned that all files of one project should have the same encoding.